# find order directories first, files last

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to list all files using find, so that the directories are listed first (in order) and files at same depth are listed after:

```
test/test1/1.txt
test/test2/1.txt
test/xtest/1.txt
test/test.txt
```

I tried using this:

```
find -type f -printf "%d\t%p\n" | sort -nr
```

But it gives me this result:

```
test/xtest/1.txt
test/test2/1.txt
test/test1/1.txt
test/test.txt
```

Is there a way using find or should I look for something else?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort by *filename* first, then - by *depth*:

```
find . -type f -printf "%d %p\n" | sort -k2 | sort -k1,1nr
```